# how do i fix the error in this python code

Tags: python, arduino, anaconda, serial-port, spyder

getting the return error for the code that I am running. since this is a copied code I did not write it and am not sure how to fix it. OP WINDOWS 10 anaconda3 python 3.7.6

CODE:

```
#Purpose: Save data from an arduino into file using python
#Name: Kira Kemock
#Date: 7/24/2020
#filename = myfile.txt
import serial                ****LINE 5*****
port_addr='COM4' # com port of the arduino
baud='9600'
file_name='mydata.txt' # this file will be saved in the same location as the py file

with serial.Serial(port_addr,baud) as port, open(file_name,"w+", 256) as outf:
    for i in range(200): #read 200 lines into the file
        fullline = port.readline()
        line = str(fullline)
        outf.write(line)
        outf.write('\n')
        outf.flush()
```

RETURN:

```
runfile('C:/PythonCode/SaveSerial.py', wdir='C:/PythonCode', post_mortem=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\PythonCode\SaveSerial.py", line 5, in <module>
    import serial

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'serial'
```

LINE 5 HAS BEEN MARKED WITH ****LINE 5***** IN ORDER TO HELP IDENTIFY THE ISSUE

Comment: "serial" isn't part of the standard library and must be installed separately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install serial. you can do it with

```
pip3 install serial
```

Open powershell and type this